# weblogic JMS queue message not rolled back on exception

Tags: jms, weblogic-10.x, spring-jms

We weblogic10.3.4 and JMS queue set up on that ,below is the message listener code and it uses the Spring JMS , The MessageProducer is set to ClientAcknowledgeMode . When there is an exception occurs , the message is still moved out of the queue and getting rolle back ,anything wrong with below code?

```
public class EmailListener implements MessageListener,ExceptionListener{



    private EmailSend emailSend;



    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    public void onMessage(Message message){
        ObjectMessage om ;
        try {
            if(message instanceof ObjectMessage) {
                om = (ObjectMessage)message;
                emailSend.sendEmail((Map<String, String>)om.getObject());
                //throw new JMSException("Test");
                 om.acknowledge();

            }
        }
        catch(MailException me) {
            logger.error("Mail server exception in sending email",me);
            throw new RuntimeException(me);
        }catch(JMSException jmse) {
            logger.error("Error in sending email",jmse);
            throw new RuntimeException(jmse);

        }

    }

    public void setEmailSend(EmailSend emailSend){
        this.emailSend = emailSend;
    }

    public void onException(JMSException jmse){
        logger.error("Exception in sending email",jmse);

    }
    public void acknowledge(
    ) throws JMSException{

    }
}
```

Below is the Spring config

```
<!--Spring JMS Message Listener Container -->
    <bean id="jmsContainer"
        class="org.springframework.jms.listener.DefaultMessageListenerContainer"
        p:autoStartup="true" p:destination-ref="queue"
        p:destinationResolver-ref="jmsDestinationResolver"
        p:connectionFactory-ref="authenticationConnectionFactory"
        p:exceptionListener-ref="emailListener"
        p:messageListener-ref="emailListener" />
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to clarify a bit. The headline indicates your messages does not roll back to Queue as they should, while the text in the post says the messages are rolled back.

Never the less, a few pointers to get your roll back behaviour correct:

Don't rely on acknowledgements. Actually, they are not intended to be application logic level redelivery. You can read some details about it [here](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/2.0.x/api/org/springframework/jms/listener/AbstractMessageListenerContainer.html). So, acks won't get you redelivery on exception, but transactions will.

You could set p:sessionTransacted="true" on your DMLC. That would probably be what you want - the message would be rolled back to the queue if you get an exception.

If you start to include database connections in this, you should perhaps instead grab the Jta transaction manager from the WebLogic JNDI repository and inject it as p:transactionManager propery on the DMLC, as the session transaction only supports one resource transactions.